# Whats is the correct way to sum different dataframe columns in a list in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to sum different columns in a spark dataframe.

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
cols = ["A.p1","B.p1"]
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[4,89],[12,60]],schema=cols)

# 1. Works
df = df.withColumn('sum1', sum([df[col] for col in ["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"]]))

#2. Doesnt work
df = df.withColumn('sum1', F.sum([df[col] for col in ["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"]]))

#3. Doesnt work
df = df.withColumn('sum1', sum(df.select(["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"])))
```

Why isn't approach #2. & #3. not working?
I am on Spark 2.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because,

```
# 1. Works
df = df.withColumn('sum1', sum([df[col] for col in ["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"]]))
```

Here you are using python in-built sum function which takes iterable as input,so it works. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum

```
#2. Doesnt work
df = df.withColumn('sum1', F.sum([df[col] for col in ["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"]]))
```

Here you are using pyspark sum function which takes column as input but you are trying to get it at row level.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum

```
#3. Doesnt work
df = df.withColumn('sum1', sum(df.select(["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"])))
```

Here, df.select() returns a dataframe and trying to sum over a dataframe. In this case, I think, you got to iterate rowwise and apply sum over it.

Comment: Thanks.Using native python sum() is not benefitting from spark optimization. so whats the spark way of doing it?

Comment: If you are using only two columns as mentioned, you can sum it straightaway,  df.withColumn('sum1',df['`A.p1`']+df['`B.p1`']). But if there are many columns, can use UDF.

Comment: I want to pass n columns in a list and sum it. my list of columns will change based on user input

Comment: btw, why native python sum() is not benefiting?

Comment: its not a pypark function so it wont be really be completely benefiting from spark right.

Comment: you are trying to do row wise computation, summing each row separately. In this case, I believe native function is good enough.  Also, almost all pyspark functions work at column level and not at row level.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** `builtins.sum` is just fine.

---

Following your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690615/whats-is-the-correct-way-to-sum-different-dataframe-columns-in-a-list-in-pyspark#comment82346351_47692552):

> Using native python sum() is not benefitting from spark optimization. so whats the spark way of doing it

[and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690615/whats-is-the-correct-way-to-sum-different-dataframe-columns-in-a-list-in-pyspark#comment82347898_47692552)

> its not a pypark function so it wont be really be completely benefiting from spark right.

I can see you are making incorrect assumptions.

Let's decompose the problem:

```
[df[col] for col in ["`A.p1`","`B.p1`"]]
```

creates a list of `Columns`:

```
[Column<b'A.p1'>, Column<b'B.p1'>]
```

Let's call it `iterable`.

`sum` reduces output by taking elements of this list and calling `__add__` method (`+`). Imperative equivalent is:

```
accum = iterable[0]
for element in iterable[1:]:
    accum = accum + element
```

This gives `Column`:

```
Column<b'(A.p1 + B.p1)'>
```

which is the same as calling

```
df["`A.p1`"] + df["`B.p1`"]
```

No data has been touched and when evaluated it is benefits from all Spark optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

## Addition of multiple columns from a list into one column

I tried a lot of methods and the following are my observations:

1. PySpark's `sum` function doesn't support column addition (Pyspark version 2.3.1)
2. Built-in python's `sum` function is working for some folks but giving error for others (might be because of conflict in names)

In your 3rd approach, the expression (inside python's `sum` function) is returning a PySpark DataFrame.

So, the addition of multiple columns can be achieved using the `expr` function in PySpark, which takes an expression to be computed as an input.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

cols_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Creating an addition expression using `join`
expression = '+'.join(cols_list)

df = df.withColumn('sum_cols', expr(expression))
```

This gives us the desired sum of columns. We can also use any other complex expression to get other output.